# Postman - POST users into BIM 360 bug?

Tags: post, postman, autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/users-POST/#example

Following the link above, I am trying to create a new user in BIM 360 using Postman but I am unable to set their name. I tried to create a similar user into my own account as shown below.

URI:
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/hq/v1/accounts/:account_id/users

Method: POST

Authorization: Bearer **************************

Content-Type: `application/json`

Body:

```
{
    "email": "john.smith@mail.com",
    "company_id": ************************************,
    "nickname": "Johnny",
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Smith",
    "address_line_1": "The Fifth Avenue",
    "address_line_2": "#301",
    "city": "shanghai",
    "postal_code": "20000",
    "state_or_province": "Shanghai",
    "country": "China",
    "phone": "1234567",
    "company": "Autodesk",
    "job_title": "software developer",
    "industry": "IT",
    "about_me": "Nothing here"
}
```

However the result when sending this request creates a new user with the name `New Member` as shown below.

```
{
    "account_id": ************************************,
    "role": "account_user",
    "status": "not_invited",
    "company_id": ************************************,
    "company_name": "Autodesk",
    "last_sign_in": null,
    "default_role": null,
    "default_role_id": null,
    "access_level": "account_user",
    "id": ************************************,
    "email": "john.smith@mail.com",
    "name": "New Member",
    "nickname": "Johnny",
    "first_name": "New",
    "last_name": "Member",
    "uid": null,
    "image_url": "http://static-dc.autodesk.net/etc/designs/v201412151200/autodesk/adsk-design/images/autodesk_header_logo_140x23.png",
    "address_line_1": "The Fifth Avenue",
    "address_line_2": "#301",
    "city": "New York",
    "postal_code": "10011",
    "state_or_province": "New York",
    "country": "United States",
    "phone": "(634)329-2353",
    "company": "Autodesk",
    "job_title": "Software Developer",
    "industry": "IT",
    "about_me": "Nothing here",
    "created_at": "2016-07-27T19:09:31.998Z",
    "updated_at": "2019-02-19T08:59:57.852Z"
}
```

Is this a bug? When I check BIM 360 the user is created with the name New Member and I am unable to create any members with my own custom names. Are there any solutions to this?

Comment: Can you try again and leave the `name` field out, same as the example in the endpoint doc?

Comment: I removed `name` but it still creates a new user with the name `New Member`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `name` attribute will not be synced between BIM360 and Identity services until the user logs in for the first time.

Before then `name` won’t be set and will default to `New Member`.